# $_FILE does not set for some files

Tags: php, file-upload

$_FILE works fine if I upload **myPCVideo.mov** and php shows :

```
Array ( [name] => simpsons.mov [type] => video/quicktime [tmp_name] => F:\xampp\tmp\php1B6.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 99279 )
```

but if I try to upload **myMobileVideo.MOV** php says

> Notice: Undefined index: file in F:\xampp\htdocs\videos\post.php on
>   line 2

I dont know why php does not $_FILE does not set updoaded file attributes wen i use video with upper case extension..?

**HTML Script:**

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="" class="submt_post" />
</form>
```

**PHP file script:**

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES['file']);
?>
```

Comment: Show the codes of F:\xampp\htdocs\videos\post.php

Comment: @Shiplu
<?php
    print_r($_FILES['file']);
?>

Comment: Use ` print_r($_FILES);` only

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was max file upload issue.. after increasing in php.ini it works for .MOV extension, actually the video size is more than 8M.

But thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\Apache\xampp\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\stack.php on line 2
```

Call Stack

```
 1  0.0017  333248  {main}( )   ..\stack.php:0
```

All you where missing is variable declaration

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    print_r($_FILES['file']);
}
```

Response

```
 Array ( [name] => 1.MOV [type] => video/quicktime [tmp_name] => C:\Apache\xampp\tmp\php81EB.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 88 )
```

Thanks

:)